# Why do Germans constantly use the word "Sie"

Tags: pronoun, address

I've been doing some reading for the Goethe Institut, and whenever they tell me to do something they use the word "Sie", for instance:

> Wir geben Ihnen mehr Informationen. Finden Sie die passenden Fragen.

or

> Bitte setzen Sie die Verben im Präsens ein.

I'm especially curious since it seems totally unnecessary to write "Sie" in the contexts in which they were used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: This question is highly unclear. Is it about *Sie* vs. *du*? About the imperative? Literally about what *Sie* means (pronoun of address)? Voting to close.

Comment: For me this is a question about culture - the OP seems to be used to use "Du" everywhere, his mothertongue might not much distinguish between you and you...

Comment: @winner28: What do you expect to have written instead of "Sie"? Why does it seem *totally unnecessary to write "Sie" in the contexts in which they were used.*?

Comment: If Björns and RHas answers fit to your question, you should rephrase it. First, the "constantly" in the title is misleading, imho. Then you might show the contrast to "Du" ("Finde die passenden Fragen") and mention the word imperative to make the context clear. Then I would consider to vote for reopening.

Comment: I really like to reopen the question - after it gets clarified by OP.

Comment: Not only Germans do it. Also Austrians, Swiss and everybody else who speaks German does it. Please do not mix up *Germans* (citizens of Germany) and *German speaking people.* Compare it with US citizens: They speak English, but they are not English.

Comment: Because it’s correct German.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, when you drop the subject of a sentence, the sentence becomes incomplete.

There is an exception in imperative mood: When the subject is second person singular (*du*) or second person plural (*ihr*), it is usually omitted:

> - Finde <s>du</s> die passenden Fragen!
> - Findet <s>ihr</s> die passenden Fragen!

This omission is an exception, not a rule. It does not apply to the honorific address *Sie*:

> - Finden Sie die passenden Fragen!

I suppose that the question has arisen, because the situation is different in English. The three German sentences above translate to the same English sentence:

> Find the appropriate questions!

Answer (score 1):

The imperative plural with *Sie* takes the same form as indicative plural of the first and third person. If *Sie* is omitted, the sentence becomes ambiguous.

*Finden die Fragen* could be read as *Finden Sie die Fragen* (*Find the questions*), but also as *Wir finden die Fragen* (*We find the questions*) or *Sie finden die Fragen* (*They find the questions*/*You find the questions*).

This differs from the other imperative where a *du* is unnecessary and therefore omitted. The reason is probably that the *Sie*-imperative is much younger.

Answer (score -1):

These sentences are in the imperative mood (well, kind of, but we will come to that). Let us take a step back and look at the indicative mood.

> You find the questions.

This would be

> Du findest die Fragen.

if "you" is singular and

> Ihr findet die Fragen.

if "you" is plural.

However, German, as many other languages, has developed to not use second person singular (Du) for addressing people in certain formal contexts. Some other languages (Spanish, French) use the second person plural instead. (And this is also how English lost the distinction but second person singular and plural.) German instead uses third person plural as a polite address for either one or several persons:

> Sie finden die Fragen.

(Here, the *sie* is always capitalized as *Sie* to indicate that this functions as second person even though it is grammatically third person. We do not see this at the beginning of a sentence, of course.)

Now let's switch to the imperative mood.

> Find the questions!

This is in singular

> Finde die Fragen!

and in plural

> Findet die Fragen!

What about the polite form, though? Remember that structurally this is third person, and an imperative does not make sense for third person. The form that has developped for this (and that I suspect is originally a subjunctive, Konjunktiv) is

> Finden Sie die Fragen!

So nothing is superfluous and nothing can be omitted. This is just how to say

> Find the questions!

using the polite form.

As to when to use "Du" and when to use "Sie", this is a more complicated question about culture. You will find some answers on this site. In the context of the current question, we can say that the book would have used "Du" if it was aimed at children.